What are the consequences of molten salt oxidizing (solar thermal)?
What are the consequences to a solar thermal plant if its molten salt oxidizes?
There are many mixtures of different salts used in solar thermal plants, which use the salt to store energy (in the form of heat). The specific mix of salt (and its impurities) affects the properties of the salt oxidizing -- such as the temperature at which it oxidizes.
My question is: what are all of the consequences that I should be aware-of when the molten salt (when used both in a tank and as a heat-transfer-fluid) oxidizes?
It's obvious that salt oxidizing will corrode steel pipes used to transfer the molten salt. But what else?
Does it change the thermal properties of the salt such that the salt will need to be replaced? Does it introduce any other safety considerations that would require the salt to be replaced?

Are the pipes steel, or is the material chosen specifically? Are you assuming steel or have you checked?

If the melting point of the oxides of the salt (assuming they are generated) used are higher than intended then there is a risk of freezing during operation which could be an additional issue. This is an article on the general risk of freezing. Source 
